# Apache mod_rewrite Redirect Alternative

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using:

> Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com

Problem is that it appends the end of the first to the new domain.

I need an alternative to redirect all requests to the new domain with out appending what follows the /.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_alias for that, the syntaxis will be like this:

```
Redirect /something http://www.example.com/new_something
```

If you need something more complex, mod_alias has more options and commands, check [mod_alias on the official documentation](http://www.askapache.info//2.3/mod/mod_alias.html), or this [askapache post](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this in your .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !oldexample.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `newdomain.com` is pointing to a new IP/host. You can use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` for its regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^ http://newdomain.com
```